# scrollable div is not working in android emulator,iphone simulator

Tags: android-emulator, ios-simulator, cordova

I am using phonegap.
I want to keep a fixed header and footer,and i want to scroll the content in between them. For that i used div with:

```
div
{
    width: 249px;
    height: 299px;

    background-color:Gray;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

style. 
But the div is not scrolling.
But in browser it is fine.

Answer (score 1):

iOS doesn't allow scrolling within an element (div with overflow:scroll/auto or frames) so you can either design your site around that (usually for the best) or you can try iScroll, which is a javascript plugin designed to re-instate this ability:

http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Div scrolling does work in iOS if this property is added:

-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch